# How to get the ItemId of save-to-sent copy when sending mail via EWS

Tags: email, office365, exchangewebservices

The EWS documentation says that to send a message and save a copy to the Sent Items folder, you should [use the CreateItem operation with a MessageDisposition value of SendAndSaveCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_sendnewews).

```
   <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
     <m:SavedItemFolderId>
       <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />
     </m:SavedItemFolderId>
     <m:Items>
       <t:Message>
         <t:Subject>Company Soccer Team</t:Subject>
         <t:Body BodyType="HTML">Are you interested in joining?</t:Body>
         <t:ToRecipients>
           <t:Mailbox>
             <t:EmailAddress>sadie@contoso.com </t:EmailAddress>
           </t:Mailbox>
         </t:ToRecipients>
       </t:Message>
     </m:Items>
   </m:CreateItem>
```

On success, "the server responds to the CreateItem request with a CreateItemResponse message that includes a ResponseCode value of NoError, which indicates that the email was created successfully, and the ItemId of the newly created message."

Using EWS against Office 365, this works *almost* successfully. The message is sent, the copy is saved to Sent Items... but the ItemId of the saved copy is **not** returned in the response:

```
   <m:CreateItemResponse>
     <m:ResponseMessages>
       <m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
         <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
         <m:Items />
       </m:CreateItemResponseMessage>
     </m:ResponseMessages>
   </m:CreateItemResponse>
```

Is there a way to direct the EWS server to actually return the ItemId of the saved copy? Alternatively, what's the preferred mechanism for locating the saved copy once the send completes?

Comment: I should note that I'm specifying the outbound message via `<t:MimeContent CharacterSet="utf-8">...</t:MimeContent>`. I don't *think* this should make any difference.

Comment: There's a possibility that specifying `<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />` in the SOAP header would cause the EWS service to return the ItemId. Unfortunately, my EWS client library doesn't support this `RequestServerVersion` value, so testing this hypothesis may have to be left to the next person to have this issue...

Comment: As far as I can tell, setting `RequestServerVersion` doesn't change the response.

Answer (score 5):

Evidently the documentation is either wrong or inapplicable. [This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/02/25/determining-the-id-of-a-sent-message-by-using-extended-properties-with-the-ews-managed-api.aspx) matches my experience: no ItemId is returned from a SendAndSaveCopy `CreateItem` request. It suggests the following:

`Simply stamp your e-mail message with a custom extended property when you create the message, and then use that extended property to find the message in the Sent Items folder after it has been sent.`

A commenter suggests that rather than using an expensive `FindItems`-with-SearchFilter call to locate the custom-property-stamped saved copy, you should instead do the following:

`1.   Set your extended prop.`

`2.   Do a FindItem with NO restriction against the sent items folder, SORTED by creation date descending with a indexed page view of about 5.  Include your extended prop in the PropertySet.`

`3.   Iterate across the results looking for your extended prop.`